# How to create custom error page in struts2?

Tags: java, exception

I am very new to J2EE and don't know how to create custom error page. I have tried with struts.xml as returning input from action but that is not a solution. I want to make global page which is called if any exception arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file `Error404.jps` & `ExceptionHandler.jsp` inside `error` directory in webroot. for more issue you can take help from here https://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-global-custom-exception-example/
just put this code in `web.xml` inside web-app tag

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/Error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

```
   <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/ExceptionHandler.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoul read "Global Exception Handling". Here is the link:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-handling.html

There is an example configuration.